# Calculate electric fields given a point charge and dielectric?

Tags: electrostatics, dielectric

I am currently trying to understand how to calculate the electric fields in space if I have an infinite plane that serves as a dielectric and right above the plane I place a point charge Q.
I have an example simulation from falstad and it should look this:

[image: Simulation result]

From my textbook I know that a point charge creates a radial electric field $ E=\frac{Q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 R^2} \cdot \vec{a_R} $ in vacuum. In a dielectric it becomes $ E=\frac{Q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 \epsilon_r R^2} \cdot \vec{a_R} $. But as far as I understand: Since the plane becomes polarized by the electric field of the point charge it creates an equivalent bound surface charge and volume charge within the dielectric and therefore creates its own electric field aswell. By superposition those two have to be added. Assuming a linear, homogenous, isotropic material for the dielectric the polarization is $ P=\epsilon_0 \cdot \epsilon_r \cdot E $ . But what is E here? Is it the electric field created by the point charge or do I have to plug in the "superpositioned E field" (which I am actually trying to calculate)? I am so lost right now...

Comment: $E$ it's the only existing electric field: the total electric field due to all charges (free and bound). That said I don't know how to solve this problem since there are few symmetries to exploit: it's hard to deduce anything from Maxwell's equations in this case.